# QML: Center variable text and image

Tags: qml, qtquick2

I need to horizonally center a variable-length text (red box) and an image (yellow box) in a big box (green box). The text shall wrap if it does not fit the box.

[image: drawing]

Existing code:

```
Item {
    id: bigBox
    x: 255
    y: 0
    width: 800
    height: 100
    Image {
        id: imageBox
        source: "image.png"
        width: 52
        height: 46
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 12
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        horizontalAlignment: Image.AlignLeft
        verticalAlignment: Image.AlignVCenter
        fillMode: Image.Pad
    }

    Text {
        id: textBox
        anchors.left: symbol.right
        anchors.leftMargin: 12
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        text: qsTr("heading text")
        font.pixelSize: 36
        font.bold: true
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignCenter
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Actual running code and a real screenshot showing the problem:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: mask
    x: 0
    y: 0
    width: 800
    height: 430
    color: "#FFFFFF"
    property int pageState: 0
    Rectangle {
        x: 0
        y: 0
        width: 111
        height: 100
        color: "#0000FF"
    }
    Item {
        id: whitespace
        x: 117
        y: 0
        width: 800-x
        height: 100
        Row {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            Image {
                id: symbol
                source: "../img/pepper.png"
                width: 52
                height: 46
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                fillMode: Image.Pad
            }
            Text {
                id: heading
                property var texts: ["Active Blabla","Active Blaaaaaaah Blaaaah ","Active Blabla and Blaaaaaaah Blaaaah"]
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                color: "#333191"
                text: texts[pageState]
                font.family: "Liberation Sans"
                font.pixelSize: 36
                font.bold: true
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                wrapMode: Text.WrapAtWordBoundaryOrAnywhere
                textFormat: Text.PlainText
                width: Math.min(150,contentWidth)
            }
        }
    }
    Rectangle {
        id: stage
        x: 0
        y: 106
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height-y
        color: "#FFFF00"
    }
    Timer {
        interval: 1000 // milliseconds
        triggeredOnStart: true
        repeat: true
        running: true
        onTriggered: {
            pageState=(pageState+1)%3;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

The white area top right is the green box in the first picture. The timer simply runs through the three texts, like the real application would do.

Changing the first parameter of Math.min() to 600 does not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

My set of hacks to solve that problem:

```
Item {
    // ...
    Text {
        function escapeHTML(text)
        {
            return text.replace(/&/g,"&amp;").replace(/</g,"&lt;").replace(/>/g,"&gt;").replace(/"/g,"&quot;");
        }

        function toHTML(imageUrl,text)
        {
            var textlines=escapeHTML(text).replace(/\r?\n/,"\n").split("\n");
            var retval="<center>";
            retval=retval+'<table><tr>';
            if (imageUrl!="") {
                retval=retval+'<td rowspan="'+(textlines.length)+'"><img src="'+imageUrl+'"></td>';
                retval=retval+'<td rowspan="'+(textlines.length)+'">&nbsp;</td>';
            }
            for (var i=0; i<textlines.length; i++) {
                if (i>0) {
                    retval=retval+"<tr>";
                }
                retval=retval+'<td>'+textlines[i]+'</td></tr>';
            }
            retval=retval+'</table>';
            retval=retval+"</center>";
            return retval;
        }

        anchors.fill: parent
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        textFormat: Text.RichText
        text: toHtml("../img/pepper.png",qsTr("heading"))
    }
}
```

- `<center>` centers the text in the available space, but not the image
  (it stays left - bug!).
- `<table>` can be centered by `<center>`, and it can contain the
  image.
- Wrapping does not work as expected, so the translated text returned
  by `qsTr()` has to contain linebreaks at the right positions.
- `toHTML()` splits at the linebreaks and generates table rows from that.
- The image needs a table cell with `rowspan`, or else the image is placed too high relative to the text.
- And finally, `verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter` places all of that vertically centered -- except for the table borders that I luckily don't need. (If you are bored, add `border=1` to the `<table>` tag.)

And no, the HTML and CSS subset supported by `Text.RichText` does not support vertical alignment. The rendering engine behaves like ancient browsers, you have to stack hacks and workarounds as if it was still 1996.

Answer (score 0):

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2

Item {
    id: bigBox

    width: 800
    height: 100

    Row {
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        Image {
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

            source: "blue.png"
        }

        Text {
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

            // maximum width of the text
            width: Math.min(150, contentWidth)

            text: qsTr("heading")
            wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically works, but needs a little bit of fine-tuning (of some details omitted in the question). Thanks!

Comment: Ooops, sorry, no, it does NOT work as expected. The text is too small and breaks out through to top and the bottom of the green box. Adjusting the magic number in Math.min to larger values breaks centering for shorter texts.

Comment: It's like you're using `Math.max` instead of `Math.min`. Or maybe adding red/green boxes changes something? Can you update the code example?

Comment: I kind of know why it's happening. When the text is updated, it's wrapped to the current width, so the contentWidth never grow bigger and the recalculation of the width never procs. Can't think of a non-hacky solution now...